# How to remember state during recomposition in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, state

```
@SuppressLint("DiscouragedApi")
@Composable
fun PuzzleScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    letter: String,
    puzzleViewModel: PuzzleViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {


    val state by puzzleViewModel.viewState.collectAsState()

    /..../
}
```

The problem is that when I go from PuzzleScreen to the second and then return to the PuzzleScreen. Then the system re-updates PuzzleScreen screen. I need to make sure that the state is preserved and remembered. How to do it?

If it’s not difficult, share sites explaining how to do this or use it on GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `hiltViewModel()`, the ViewModel instance created by Hilt will be scoped to the `NavGraphEntry` by default. This means that once this destination is removed from the backstack, the ViewModel is cleared. After revisiting the destination, a new instance is created.

First, make sure that you handle the navigation properly. If you want to navigate to a follow-up screen without clearing the current destination from the backstack, use

```
navController.navigate(Destination.SecondDestination.route)
```

And then to return to the previous destination on the backstack, do

```
navController.popBackStack()
```

This way, the ViewModel state should not be lost.

As an alternative, you can pass a `NavGraphEntry` manually to which the ViewModel should be scoped to. If you pass the `NavGraphEntry` of the root Composable, the ViewModel will be available until the application is closed. This has to happen outside of your Composable, for example, in your NavHost. The code would look like this:

```
composable(Destination.FirstDestination.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
        val parentEntry = remember(navBackStackEntry) {
            navController.getBackStackEntry(Destination.RootDestination.route)
        }
        val puzzleViewModel = hiltViewModel<PuzzleViewModel>(parentEntry)

        PuzzleScreem(
            // ...
            puzzleViewModel = puzzleViewModel
        })
    }
```

Note that the behaviour you currently observe is not related to recomposition. ViewModels per definition retain their state during recomposition. Your problem is not related to *recomposition*, but rather to *navigation*.